# How to print the value with desired text in TSQL using sql server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, select

I want to select a value from my `customers` datatable. I have been asked this question in an interview.

```
Select cust_Name from customers where cust_Id=5;
```

will result as `Naresh`.

Now I want to print the value as

```
Customer Name is Naresh
```

How can I print the value like this.Thank you

Comment: The usual approach would be to learn TSQL...

Comment: Concatenate is the term you might need :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Select 'Customer Name is ' + cust_Name from customers where cust_Id=5;
```

Or

```
Declare @CustomerName varchar(50)
Select @CustomerName = cust_Name from customers where cust_Id=5;
Print 'Customer Name is ' + @CustomerName ;
```

Comment: Thought that there will some statement like `print` :)

Comment: Thanks for showing two different ways in printing statement in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare them

```
Declare @CstName nvarchar(100)
Select @CstName = cust_Name from customers where cust_Id=5;
Print 'Customer Name is ' + @CstName ;
```

This is the bettre way while using TSQL as you asked

Answer (score 2):

You can use concat()

```
Select concat('Customer Name is',cust_Name) as values from customers where cust_Id=5;
```

[Click here to learn more about concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp)